# Reset Zend_Paginator page to first page on select change

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I have a page with a form that contains five selects (drop-down lists) which filter my set of data, and at bottom has pagination (Zend_Paginator) . My Form which has get method is submited each time a select change its value and I want that my page number to be reset to first page.

At this moment when the form is submited the page remain unchanged (current page) because it is contained in the URL and I do not know how to modify it after submit.

My url is something like this:

```
 .../controller/action/page/2?sec=3&subsec=10&subbus=17&act=all&subact=all
```

Any ideas how can I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the page parameters from the url itself, you can build your form action without the page parameter.

```
   $form->setAction('/controller/action');
```

Or, you can modify the paginator variable to point to page 1.

```
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
```

Comment: If I modify paginator variable to point to page 1 then the pagination doesnt work any more (always point to page 1 and I do not want this). I want to point to page 1 only when select change else I want paginator to work as default

Comment: Normally the page tracking is done by $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page); where $page is the get parameter page in your url. You can retain that code by assigning $page = 1 at appropriate locations. If you can paste the code of the form and the resulting page, we can check.

Comment: You are wright, but I do not know the appropriate location where I could make $page = 1. By the way my from is created in view (I do not have a form created with Zend_Form, but if this is a must I will created that way, although I don't think this is the problem). I do not have a resulting page, because page remain the same each time but with different data displayed (it only filter data and display filtered results), so each time the form is submitted the page is reloaded with new parameter values.

Comment: then you can just do - <form method="get" action="/controller/action"> right? The paginator will take care of the rest of things.